# TryUpdateModel is browser specific

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I just ran into a scenario where TryUpdateModel works perfectly for Chrome and other browsers and does not work in IE9.  Before I start splitting code, does anyone know why TryUpdateModel is browser specific?

**EDIT**

(To further elaborate): I model bound the form data and it works perfectly, but when I retrieve the original object and call TryUpdateModel on it (assuming that it's going to use the same method that model binding used to try to update the model) it does not update the model in IE9... Was this a bad assumption to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's far more likely that the client-side form is behaving in a browser-specific manner, which is preventing a parameter from being sent to the server correctly. Rather than splitting code, just put a breakpoint in your controller action and look at the request parameters.

Comment: I'm perhaps making a bad assumption here that I'll also add as an edit to the post.  I model bound the form data and it works perfectly, but when I retrieve the original object and call TryUpdateModel on it (assuming that it's going to use the same method that model binding used to try to update the model), it doesn't work in IE9 (but just fine in Chrome).  Was this a bad assumption to make?

Comment: @Rikon: What do you get when you check `ModelState.IsValid` in your action? `TryUpdateModel` will return false if the model is not valid (e.g. if a Required field is not provided), even if it was capable of creating your object.

Comment: Argh, yeah, I found the model state error.  We were using an old way to get model state errors and it didn't catch this. Thanks for your patience. Out of curiosity, any idea why model state is valid in one browser and not in another. The error happened on a blank ModelState key... How did it even try to bind an empty key

Comment: @Rikon: Again, I'm suspecting it has something to do with the way your HTML is interacting with the browser. One browser is obviously sending a different parameter value across the wire: maybe sending an empty string for a parameter that the other browsers simply don't include?

Comment: I'm almost positive I know what's happened and why no one else has seen this behavior.  We've wrapped subsonic with our own eager loading option.  This is done by decorating the poco to make it aware of how to eager load.  I'm almost positive that it's these changes to the poco that caused IE9 to mishandle the model when it was passed to the view.  Thank you again for your perspective and help with this, I'm very grateful!